# Laravel in VScode use PHP IntelliSense extension but References of file in vendor not found

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

Like the title of my question, my laravel in vscode with PHP IntelliSense extesion.

And I want to get the references of "Auth" from "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth"

But it seems that it cant find any file in the vendor directory.

[image: p]

I've tried remove **/.git from exclude file and uncheck the "Use ignore Files".

But that just solve the original problem that it couldn't find the file in vendor by press "crtl + p" and it still can't find references in vendor now.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About facades I had the same problem.

But about finding vendor paths I think you should use intellephense, I use and I'm happy with it.

Though, if your problem is about facades and Laravel custom methods this repo will solve your issue.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/

**ide-helper is for development usage only.**